# Is it possible to alter the request body in mountebank before it gets processed ? If yes, then how can we do that?

Tags: xml, soap, mountebank

I am working on service virtualization using mountebank. I am receiving the request from test application in mountebank which contains soap xml as a request body. In that soap xml, there is a tag wsa:Tohttp://[ip]:[port]/</wsa:To> but I need to change this value with target application endpoint before it gets processed by mountebank. Please help how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you're trying to do. It certainly is possible to do advanced parsing using the [inject predicate](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/injection). Or does your processing involve using that part of the request and adjusting the response based on some transformation? If so, maybe use the [decorate behavior](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/behaviors).

Comment: I suppose he want's to modify original request - is it possible?

Comment: For what purpose? To match? If so, there's more than enough flexibility with the inject predicate without changing the request. To change before forwarding as a proxy? No, that functionality doesn't exist. Is there another reason?

Comment: Some times you could not correct the original response. 
For example you have a huge json request and forming of this request pretty complicated. And you need to check behaviour when some of the fields are changes. 
With copy/pasting and changing requests it will be too slow. 
But if we would be able to change the original request it will be awesome and easy to automate such tests.